# Google cloud function using pubsub messages to start other GCF ends with 'status: connection error'

Tags: python, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub

**Situation:**

- I have 2 google cloud functions, let's call them gcf-composer and gcf-action.
- I have a list of 70,000 unique dicts for which I want to execute the gcf-action.
- I use the gcf-composer loop over all dicts and publish a message per dict to the gcf-action topic containing the dict as payload.
- I need the gcf-composer, because running the gcf-action directly for all dicts would take more than the 9 min threshold.
- I start off the gcf-composer using the google cloud-scheduler

**Problem**
When firing off the gcf-composer on the cloud, after an x-amount of seconds, it will stop and return the following:
['connection error'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UZZCm.png)

 These are the results of 4 separate tries.

Why does it give me the "finished with status: 'connection error'", and how do i solve it? 
When I run this locally, so sending messages to topic, it works.
**Please let me know if you need any more code or information!**
**Code of gcf-composer**

```
from mlibs.pubsub import PubSubConnection
pubsub = PubSubConnection()
TOPIC_NAME = 'gcf-action-topic'

def gcf_composer(period, run_method='local', list_x, names_y):
"""Run composer given run method (local or cloud_fn)"""

for k, row in names_y.iterrows():
    # get dict of identifiers
    y = row.to_dict()

    for x in list_x:
            parameters = {'x': x, 'y': y}
            if run_method == 'local':
                c.test_local(x=x, y=y)
            elif run_method == 'cloud-fn':
                pubsub.publish_to_topic(topic_name=TOPIC_NAME, params={'params': parameters})
            else:
                print(f'Unknown run method {run_method} used. Please try again.')
```

PubSubConnection:

```
"""Interaction with the Pub/Sub Engine"""
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from google.cloud import pubsub_v1

from mlibs.utils import json
from mlibs.utils import decode
from mlibs.utils import files as fs


class PubSubConnection:

    def __init__(self):
        """Initiate a PubSub connection"""
        self.project_id = None
        self.publisher = None
        self.count = 0

        self.init_connection()

    def init_connection(self):
        """Initiates a connection given the service account"""
        self.publisher = pubsub_v1.PublisherClient(credentials=*****)
        self.project_id = credentials.project_id

    def publish_to_topic(self, topic_name, params):

        # Define the topic path
        topic_path = self.publisher.topic_path(self.project_id, topic_name)

        # Convert to ByteString
        params_bytes = json.dumps(params).encode('utf-8')

        # Publish and handle the Future
        cbl = Callable(self.count, params)
        message_future = self.publisher.publish(topic_path, data=params_bytes, test='pubsub')

        # Done callback
        message_future.add_done_callback(cbl.callback)

        # https://googleapis.dev/python/pubsub/latest/publisher/index.html#futures
        # block result
        # message_id = message_future.result()
        self.count = self.count + 1

        print(f'[pubsub][{self.count}][{topic_name}]')


class Callable:
    def __init__(self, count, params):
        self.count = count
        self.params = params

    def callback(self, message_future):
        if message_future.exception(timeout=30):
            print(f'[pubsub-except] Publishing message threw an Exception {message_future.exception()}')
        else:
            print(f'[pubsub][{self.count}][{message_future.result()}] {self.params}')
```

Comment: 2 Questions: What is the PubSubConnection function? Do you have published messages in the pubSub topic during the first seconds before your connexion error message?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Added the PubSubConnection function.Yes, so the gcf-action get's called at least 200-300 times before the connection error happens.